# Mathematical operations using floats in bash

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop

I have a script that increments a variable in a text file using sed by 0.25 (from 0.25 to 1) in a while loop and saves the new file with the extension of the increment. Everything looks fine but the script does not change the variable inside of the text file but it properly export them with their increment

```
read -p "define the increment " length_user
read -p "define the minimum length" length_start_user
length_increment=0
length_define=$length_user

length_start=$length_start_user
while [ $length_increment -lt 4 ]; do
  cp /home/students/gbroilo/Desktop/Prova.py /home/students/gbroilo/Desktop/Prova_$length_start.py

  sed -i 's/l=l0/l='$length_start'/' Prova_$length_start.py;
  length_start=$(echo "$length_start + $length_define" |bc)

  length_increment=$(( $length_increment + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: There's no reason to make a copy, then use `sed -i`. Just use `sed ... Prova.py > Prova_${length_start}.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `seq`:

```
cd /home/students/gbroilo/Desktop/
for length in $(seq $length_start_user $length_define 4); do
  sed "s/l=10/l=$length/" Prova.py  > Prova_$length.py
done
```

That said, don't modify the Python script like this. Instead, change it to take the length as a command line argument, so that you can run

```
python Prova.py 3.6
```

instead of

```
python Prova_3.6.py
```

That would be a single call to `sed`, something like:

```
sed -i '1i\
import sys
s/l=10/l = sys.argv[0]' Prova.py
```

though there's no real reason to automate this; just open the file in your favorite editor and make the change manually.

Comment: Thank you! so there is no way to keep it in bash? The reason I automate this process is because it has to be done at least 10 thousand times for a bigger simulation project

Comment: If you have to do this 10,000 times, I would strongly suggest moving the loop *into* `Prova.py`, so that you run *one* Python process, not 10,000 of them.